# How to set different value variables for each game object using same script in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am quite new into Unity and I am trying to create three different objects having one script and set a **value** variable for each instance.

I have drag and drop the script to three of the objects within my scene and set from the unity ui slots value variable to different values for each object!

Current code looks like:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class DragBall : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject gameObjectToDrag;
    public Text txt;


    public int value;

    public Vector3 GOcenter;
    public Vector3 touchPosition;
    public Vector3 offset;
    public Vector3 newGOcenter;

    RaycastHit hit;

    public bool draggingMode = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                gameObjectToDrag = hit.collider.gameObject;
                GOcenter = gameObjectToDrag.transform.position;
                touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
                offset = touchPosition - GOcenter;
                draggingMode = true;
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
            if (draggingMode) {
                touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
                newGOcenter = touchPosition - offset;
                gameObjectToDrag.transform.position = new Vector3(newGOcenter.x, 3, newGOcenter.z); // 0 means Y axis , so let the ball go horizontally only
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
            draggingMode = false;
        }

        Debug.Log(this.value);
        txt.text = this.value + "";
    }
}
```

Edited Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class DragBall : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject gameObjectToDrag;

    public Text txt;

    public Vector3 GOcenter;
    public Vector3 touchPosition;
    public Vector3 offset;
    public Vector3 newGOcenter;

    RaycastHit hit;

    public int value;

    public bool draggingMode = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        if (this.gameObjectToDrag.name == "Ball1")
        {
            this.value = 1;
        }
        else if (this.gameObjectToDrag.name == "Ball2")
        {
            this.value = 2;
        }
        else if (this.gameObjectToDrag.name == "Ball3")
        {
            this.value = 3;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                this.gameObjectToDrag = hit.collider.gameObject;
                GOcenter = this.gameObjectToDrag.transform.position;
                touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
                offset = touchPosition - GOcenter;
                draggingMode = true;
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
            if (draggingMode) {
                touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
                newGOcenter = touchPosition - offset;

                if (this.gameObjectToDrag.name == "Ball1") {
                    this.gameObjectToDrag.transform.position = new Vector3(newGOcenter.x, 1, newGOcenter.z); // 0 means Y axis , so let the ball go horizontally only
                }
                else if (this.gameObjectToDrag.name == "Ball2")
                {
                    this.gameObjectToDrag.transform.position = new Vector3(newGOcenter.x, 2, newGOcenter.z); // 0 means Y axis , so let the ball go horizontally only
                }
                else if (this.gameObjectToDrag.name == "Ball3")
                {
                    this.gameObjectToDrag.transform.position = new Vector3(newGOcenter.x, 3, newGOcenter.z); // 0 means Y axis , so let the ball go horizontally only
                }

            }
            txt.text = this.value + "";
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
            draggingMode = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like for each object I touch with mouse to show current value variable . Right now is showing 0 for all.

Is it that I should create different script for each object and assign the script to each object seperately? that doesnt just sound correct way for me idk why, but there must be something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't initialize the `value` variable so it becomes `0` when attached to the 3 Objects. Even if you initialize it to a number, it will still be that on every instance.

You need a way to initialize the value variable on each `GameObject`. To do that, you also need a way to *distinguish* each one of the `GameObject`. This can be done by comparing the current name of the GameObject, the tag, the layer or the GameObject instance.

The example below uses the name of the GameObject to initialize the `value` variable in the `Start` function. Let's say they are named "Obj1",  "Obj2" and  "Obj3":

```
void Start()
{
    //Use 1 for Object 1
    if (this.gameObject.name == "Obj1")
    {
        value = 1;
    }
    //Use 3 for Object 2
    else if (this.gameObject.name == "Obj2")
    {
        value = 2;
    }
    //Use 3 for Object 3
    else if (this.gameObject.name == "Obj3")
    {
        value = 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added exactly how you said, still not working, I am now doubting if I have setup correctly the script into each obejct, well what I did I just drag and drop the script file to each obejct and assing each object to gameObjectToDrag and set value variable different for each object, still no difference

Comment: This is very simple thing to do. Why not take screesnhots of the each of the 3 gameobjects then post the links here in the comment section. I want to take a look at it. Also take another screenshot of the Console tab log that shows it is still showing `0`. Finally, update your question and EDIT under it then include your new code that shows your implementation from my answer. Do not remove your original code. Just add EDIT + your new code. You are doing something wrong but I need these to figure out what it is.

Comment: I think you asnwer is right, I just had to move your code into update() method so now I can see the text label is changing to a value depending on which object I am dragging! I will check your answer as correct! Thanks for helping on this1

Comment: It's better in the `Start` function otherwise you will run into issues when you try to modify it later on because the `Update` function will keep running. That code is supposed to run **once** only. Glad you got it working!

Comment: I am getting when that moved to start()
UnassignedReferenceException: The variable gameObjectToDrag of DragBall has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the gameObjectToDrag variable of the DragBall script in the inspector.
DragBall.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/DragBall.cs:26)

Comment: It is `Start` not `start`.

Comment: sorry it is actually already Start() but same msg error, looks like something need to be initiallized before I am using gameObjectToDrag

Comment: That's totally a different issue which has nothing to do with your original question. I suggest you create new question with your latest code.  Also double click on the error and it will take you to the line of code that is causing that error. Show the code on that line of code too and I will see if I can answer that. I just don't want to drag this into another issue.

Comment: it is this line actually:  if (this.gameObjectToDrag.name == "Ball1")
        {
            this.value = 1;
        }

Comment: will add a separate question for this! thnx alot!

Comment: You don't have to create new question unless you have more questions or this comment I am about to make did not solve it. Enclose the three similar `if (this.gameObjectToDrag.name == "Ball1") { this.value = 1; }` statements with `if(this.gameObjectToDrag != null)`. This makes sure `gameObjectToDrag` is not `null` before using `this.gameObjectToDrag.name`....

Answer (score 0):

If you set the value to a different number in the inspector this script should work and show a different number in your log. What I can see is that you run the `txt.text = this.value` every update. If you have one text field connected to all instances of your ball it will always show the same value. If you want the text field to show the current ball being dragged you should put that line of code in your if statement like this:

```
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            //Add line here
            txt.text = this.value + "";
            gameObjectToDrag = hit.collider.gameObject;
            GOcenter = gameObjectToDrag.transform.position;
            touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            offset = touchPosition - GOcenter;
            draggingMode = true;
        }
    }
```

If you have this value set differently for each ball it should work

[image]